# Send email in app and populate message in swift

Tags: ios, swift, email, messageui

I'm trying to add the email sending feature to my app

Now I've tried a couple of thing from tutorials but unfortunately no success

now I first want to be able to get `messageUI` to pop up with my button that I've set up, but I can't because as soon as I write `mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self` I get an error saying that the delegate can't be. Also I need to add `MFMailComposeViewController` to my class but I get multiple inheritance from `ViewController`

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: You do it _exactly the same way as you would in Objective C_. If you're having trouble with the Swift language, then break it down into pieces and look at them. I'm sure there are answers on delegates, etc. There's nothing special about the mail view controller in this regard.

Comment: well what I have that is special is that after the view pops I wanted my seletedindexpath to write in the message what was selected

Comment: 1. Where in the question does it say that? 2. Exactly in the same way as you do it in Objective C.

Comment: 1. no where that's not what I'm trying to figure out right now 2. I don't know how to do it in Objective C that's why I asked the question 3. Do you really have to be such a douche about the question? if you don't want to answer just don't you are not helping

Comment: I apologise if I come access as a douche; that is not my intention. I am trying to encourage you to ask a clear question that has not already been answered on SO.

Comment: thanks, really my main question is the top one, and I did not find any ressources. I don't understand why I get the multiple inheritance problem since it is a subclass and every tutorial I've seen does it exactly like that, also the mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self  is really something I have found nothing on either that is why I'm asking the question also trying to help someone that might have this question one day

Answer (score 0):

```
class testViewContoller : UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
  func tapButton() -> Void {
    var mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    self.presentViewController(mailVC, animated:false, completion:nil)

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks do you think that I should have a separate .swift file for this, or can I implement it in my ViewController.swift?